# Vscode extension: insert some meta text on a certain position?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I think it should be possible.

I want to make an extension that will add a specific meta text content on specific positions in the source file (depending on its content), but this content should be just visible to the user not inserted into the source of course.

Can someone point to the VSCode API which I should use for this?

Comment: look at the comment example extension

Comment: I think I found it. https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditor.setDecorations but thanks for the tip to extension examples!

Answer (score 0):

I think I found it:

https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TextEditor.setDecorations

This extensions also uses it:
https://github.com/wix/import-cost

Comment: I doubt this is what you are looking for or your question is misleading. Decorations are additional marks (like underlines under the text of a line) or colored boxes in the margin. You cannot use them to add arbitrary content between letters.

Comment: You may be right, as I didn't check it really. But it seems that decorations have multiple rendering options including text content, though need to test if can cover my case.

Comment: This seems correct https://github.com/wix/import-cost adds imports uses it

Comment: I stand corrected. I never have used decorations that way. moncao-editor (the control on which vscode is based) is simply awesome! Love it!